# Adding to the value of a key in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a Markov chain in python. Currently, when I have text such as "Would you could" and "Would you like" my key of the tuple ('Would', 'you') 'could' is overwritten by like to become ('Would', 'you') 'like' as I iterate through my text file.

I am trying to add each new value for a key to the value for that key. I.E. for the key ('Would', 'you') I want the value to show up as ('Would, 'you'): 'could', 'like'

Here is my code:

```
def make_chains(corpus):
    """Takes an input text as a string and returns a dictionary of
    markov chains."""
    dict = {}
    for line in corpus:
        line = line.replace(',', "")
        words = line.split()
        words_copy = words
        for word in range(0, len(words_copy)):
            #print words[word], words[word + 1]
            if dict[(words[word], words[word + 1])] in dict:
                dict.update(words[word+2])
            dict[(words[word], words[word + 1])] = words[word + 2]
            #print dict
            if word == len(words_copy) - 3:
                break

    return dict
```

Comment: have a look at `collections.defaultdict`.

Comment: You are looking for `defaultdict` in `collections`. Just say `d = collections.defaultdict(list)` and now each element is an empty list.

By the way, don't name your variable `dict`, as that will clash with the type of the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Simple Solution

The simple solution is to use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict


def make_chains(input_list):
    """
    Takes an input text as a list of strings and returns a dictionary of markov chains.
    """
    chain = defaultdict(list)
    for line in input_list:
        line = line.replace(',', "")
        words = line.split()
        for i in range(0, len(words) - 2):
            chain[words[i], words[i + 1]].append(words[i + 2])

    return chain
```

With this then you get:

```
$ print make_chains(["Would you like", "Would you could"])
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {('Would', 'you'): ['like', 'could']})
```

## Fixing the original

Just so you can get a better idea of what went wrong in your code, though, we can fix the original solution without using defaultdict. To do this there are a few things to mention about your original code.

To start, let's look at this statement:

```
words_copy = words
```

Does not do what you think it does, nor is it necessary. This does not create a copy of `words`, it simply creates a new variable `words_copy` and points it to the existing `words` value. Therefore, if you change `words` you change `words_copy` as well.

What you would want is `words_copy = copy.deepcopy(words)` but that's unnecessary in this case since you're not changing the state of `words` as you iterate.

Next, this line:

```
if dict[(words[word], words[word + 1])] in dict:
    dict.update(words[word+2])
```

Has a couple flaws. First, if the tuple is not already in the dict, then this will raise a key error. That's certain to happen on the first iteration. Second, the update method of dict adds the passed dict to the dict you're calling on. What you want to do is update the value of the dict at that key.

So you want:

```
if (words[word], words[word + 1]) in dict:
    # Add to the existing list
    dict(words[word], words[word + 1]).append(words[word+2])
else:
    # Create a new list
    dict(words[word], words[word + 1]) = [words[word+2]]
```

Finally, this block is unnecessary:

```
if word == len(words_copy) - 3:
    break
```

Instead, just iterate up to the third to last index as in:

```
for word in range(0, len(words) - 2):
```

Putting it altogether, you can use these changes to fix the original version:

```
def make_chains(corpus):
    """Takes an input text as a string and returns a dictionary of
    markov chains."""
    dict = {}
    for line in corpus:
        line = line.replace(',', "")
        words = line.split()
        for word in range(0, len(words) - 2):
            if (words[word], words[word + 1]) in dict:
                # Add to the existing list
                dict[(words[word], words[word + 1])].append(words[word + 2])
            else:
                # Create a new list
                dict[(words[word], words[word + 1])] = [words[word + 2]]

    return dict
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: done. The extended explanation was really helpful too!